# Did the analytic philosopher G.E.M. Anscombe write anything specifically on pornography?

Tags: anscombe

An ardent traditional Catholic, she wrote a few things on sexual promiscuity, declaring that it diminishes the beauty of so-called legitimate sex, i.e., sex that takes place in marriage. But I am curious whether she wrote anything on pornography.

Answer (score 2):

G. E. M. Anscombe's defense of [Pope Paul VI's encyclical *Humanae Vitae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanae_vitae) in "Contraception and Chastity" may be a place to look for what her arguments might be against pornography.

Although she does not use the word "pornography" she discusses "masturbation" in relationship to contraception.

[Humanae Vitae](http://w2.vatican.va/content/paul-vi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-vi_enc_25071968_humanae-vitae.html) explicitly opposes the following in section 22:

> Everything therefore in the modern means of social communication which arouses men's baser passions and encourages low moral standards, as well as every obscenity in the written word and every form of indecency on the stage and screen, should be condemned publicly and unanimously by all those who have at heart the advance of civilization and the safeguarding of the outstanding values of the human spirit. It is quite absurd to defend this kind of depravity in the name of art or culture (25) or by pleading the liberty which may be allowed in this field by the public authorities.

"Every obscenity in the written word and every form of indecency on the stage and screen" would likely include what falls under the label of pornography.

---

Anscombe, G. E. M. (1972). Contraception and chastity. Human Life Center, Saint John's University.

Pope Paul VI. Humanae Vitae. Retrieved on June 27, 2019 from http://w2.vatican.va/content/paul-vi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-vi_enc_25071968_humanae-vitae.html

Comment: +1. There's nothing I know of directly on pornography but I think you hit as close as we're going to get.